# How to take arguments at run time in docker?

Tags: go, dockerfile

I am very new to docker and i don't know how to take arguments at run time.My code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
//"flag"
"os"
"net/http"
"io/ioutil"
"reflect"
)

func main() {

var args string
//  flag.Parse()      
//   args := flag.Args()
fmt.Println("Enter the URL : ")
fmt.Scanf("%s ",&args)
fmt.Println(args)       
if len(args) < 1 {        
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(args),"Please Enter the URL")  
os.Exit(1)                                
}
retrieve(args)        //call the retrieve function                                   

}

func retrieve(url string){          //gives the  source code as 
output.

resp, err := http.Get(url)         
if err != nil{
  fmt.Println("read error is:", err)
  return 
}
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body);
if err != nil{ 
  fmt.Println("read error is:", err)
  return 
} else{
  fmt.Println(string(body))

}
}
```

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM golang:1.7-alpine

ADD . /home

WORKDIR /home

CMD ["go","run","fetchSource.go"]
```

i have commented the code where it doesn't work.i just want to take arguments at run time so that i uncomment those lines.

Comment: Please paste your code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with the following changes in Dockerfile and it also worked.

```
FROM golang:1.7-alpine

ADD . /home

WORKDIR /home
# This builds a binary first
RUN ["go", "build"]
# Now you can run the executable and pass arguments at the run time.
ENTRYPOINT ["./home"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the full command with all args like :

```
docker run myimage:latest go run fetchSource.go arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Edit :

When you specify something at the end of you docker run command, you're overwriting the "Entrypoint" or "Cmd" section of you Dockerfile. You have to specify the full command.

Comment: Thanks,it worked but can you specify why `docker run -it myapp http://www.com`shows: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"go run\": executable file not found in $PATH".